# Telegram bot await reply from user after command Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm looking for a way for a bot to wait for a reply from a user after a command. For example, you first type "/ask", then the bot waits for a plain message (not a command) from the user and after the user replies is stores his/her reply in a variable

*I'm sure this is quite simple, but all the tutorials I've seen are in Russian and the documentation for python-telegram-api is very chaotic and I'm not the most advanced
If I'm dumb, sorry, just please help a fellow beginner out*

Comment: Hi, I wonder if you ever found a way to await for the user input. It seems to be an impossible task with asyncio and python-telegram-bot

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this was pointless. I thought you couldn't use arguments, but the post I read was 5 years old so... I'm stupid. I just used arguments instead, thanks for the help tho, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

here's the code that takes user's input and stores it in the "store_user_input" variable.

```
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, 
CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, 
CallbackContext
from telegram import Update

logging.basicConfig(
format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - % 
(levelname)s - %(message)s', 
level=logging.INFO
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# function to handle the /start command
def startcommand(update:Update, context: 
CallbackContext) -> None:
first_name = update.message.chat.first_name
update.message.reply_text\
        (
        f'Welcome to the bot, {first_name}, 
what are you interested in?'
        )

# function to handle and store user input
def text(update:Update, context: 
CallbackContext) -> None:
text_received = update.message.text
store_user_input = text_received

# function to handle the /help command
def helpcommand(update:Update, context: 
CallbackContext) -> None:
update.message.reply_text('Here is a list of 
all available commands:\n '
                          '/start - start the 
bot\n'
                          '/help - get all 
available commands\n')

# function to handle errors occured in the 
dispatcher
def errormsg(update:Update, context: 
CallbackContext) -> None:
update.message.reply_text('An error 
occured.')

# main function
def main():
# "bot_data is your .txt file with bot API token"
fo = open("bot_data")
fr = fo.read()
updater = Updater(fr)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# add handlers for start and help commands

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", startcommand))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", helpcommand))

# add an handler for normal text (not commands)
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, text))

# add an handler for errors
dispatcher.add_error_handler(errormsg)

# start bot
updater.start_polling()

# run the bot
updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can check the value by adding:

```
print("store_user_input")
```

after store_user_input line.

Comment: How do I make it wait for the input? Now it automatically executes code after it, which is annoying